# Is it necessary to use @Configuration while working with spring annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-annotations

I am working with a simple spring application to check @Configuration and @Bean(java based configuartion only),The program is working with both @Configuration and without it.So is it necessary to have it.

Here is my code,

Student.java

```
package com.cg.spring;

public class Student {

private int id;
private String name;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
}
    }
```

Faculty.java

```
package com.cg.spring;

public class Faculty {

private int empId;
private String name;
public int getEmpId() {
    return empId;
}
public void setEmpId(int empId) {
    this.empId = empId;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Faculty [empId=" + empId + ", name=" + name + "]";
}
}
```

MyConfig.java

```
package com.cg.spring;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class MyConfig {

@Bean
public Student stu()
{
     return new Student();
}

@Bean


public Faculty fac()
{
    return new Faculty();
}}
```

Client.java

```
package com.cg.spring;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import 
org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext context=new 
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfig.class);
    Student stu=(Student)context.getBean(Student.class);
    Faculty fac=(Faculty)context.getBean(Faculty.class);
    stu.setName("ajay");
    stu.setId(101);
    System.out.println(stu);

    fac.setEmpId(202);
    fac.setName("Kiran");
    System.out.println(fac);

}}
```

The output is same with or without the @Configuration

```
Student [id=101, name=ajay]
Faculty [empId=202, name=Kiran]
```

Even tried with autowiring,it is also working without @Configuration

Student.java

```
package com.cg.spring;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class Student {

private int id;
private String name;

@Autowired
private Faculty faculty;
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Faculty getFaculty() {
    return faculty;
}
public void setFaculty(Faculty faculty) {
    this.faculty = faculty;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Student [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
}}
```

Client.java

```
package com.cg.spring;

import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import 
org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

public class Client {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    ApplicationContext context=new 
   AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfig.class);
    Student stu=(Student)context.getBean(Student.class);
    Faculty fac=(Faculty)context.getBean(Faculty.class);
    stu.setName("ajay");
    stu.setId(101);
    System.out.println(stu);

    fac.setEmpId(202);
    fac.setName("Kiran");
    System.out.println(fac);

    stu.setFaculty(fac);
    System.out.println(stu.getFaculty());

}}
```

Comment: since you are doing `  ApplicationContext context=new 
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(MyConfig.class);` It works with or without `@Configuration`. But if you want to Autowire Student or Faculty or even MyConfig bean, then without `@Configuration` it doesn't work. Because, spring only scans those files with has one of spring anntotations

Comment: I modified the code to  use @Autowired,still same output in both case..

Comment: Autowired where and what?

Comment: just added at the end..plz check

Comment: I suggest a read of [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html). Look for *lite mode*. There are somethings that don't work in lite mode that work for full blown `@Configuration` classes.

Comment: @M. Deinum Excellent reference. You could convert this comment into answer. It is not a long answer but this is clear.

Comment: yes..plz make it into answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When using Java based configuration with Spring you basically have 2 options (as you already noticed). You have the option to annotate a class with `@Configuration` and have all the `@Bean` annotated methods available as beans. However you can also do this without the `@Configuration` annotation. The latter is called the so called [lite mode](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html).

When using `@Configuration` classes the beans defined in there are regular Spring beans and when calling one method from another this will always result in the same instance of a bean. Spring detects the `@Configuration` classes and treats them in a very special way (it will create a proxy for those classes).

When using lite-mode the `@Bean` methods are basically nothing more than factory methods, although they participate in (part of) the lifecycle of Spring Beans. When calling them each call will get you a new bean. Which means that, inter bean dependencies, will get you new instances each time the method gets called.

Answer (score 0):

Also I realised that if @Configuration is used defining dependencies as private is not permitted.

```
@Configuration
public class ProgrammingConfig {
    
// define bean for the fortune service
@Bean
private FortuneService javaFortuneService() {
    return new JavaFortuneService();
};
    
// define bean for java coach and inject its dependencies
@Bean
public Coach javaCoach() {
    return new JavaCoach(javaFortuneService());
}

}
```

will yield

```
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: @Bean method 'javaFortuneService' must not be private or final; change the method's modifiers to continue

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: @Bean method 'javaFortuneService' must not be private or final; change the method's modifiers to continue
```

whilst without the @Configuration annotation the program works even with a private dependency

Answer (score -1):

**@Configuration** is required because it indicates that a class declares one or more **@Bean** methods and may be processed by the Spring container to generate bean definitions and service requests for those beans at runtime. **@Configuration** annotation used for many other reasons. For example, **@Configuration** is meta-annotated with **@Component**, therefore **@Configuration** classes are candidates for component scanning (typically using Spring XML's **`<context:component-scan/>`** element) and therefore may also take advantage of @Autowired/@Inject like any regular @Component. More details references are available to the following Link - 
  [Annotation Type Configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html)

**@Bean** annotation on methods that are declared in classes not annotated with **@Configuration** is known as **“lite”** mode. In the “lite” mode, **@Bean** methods cannot declare inter-bean dependencies. Ideally, one **@Bean** method should not invoke another **@Bean** method in ‘lite’ mode.
Spring recommends that **@Bean** methods declared within **@Configuration** classes for full configuration. This kind of full mode can prevent many bugs.